# Java no se detiene en ningun breakpoint

Tags: java-ee

Quisiera saber algo sobre lo cuál casi no hay informacion.
De repente me encuentro con que ahora el Eclipse no se detiene en ningun breakpoint, no se por qué, hasta hace unas horas, y días atrás sí lo hacía sin problemas, pero ahora no entiendo que pasa. Sí estuve agregando clases nuevas para probar otra cosa que no me andaba que tiene que ver con lectura de archivo de Excel, pero al no poder hacerlo entonces descarté esa alternativa y decidí hacerlo con archivos txt, y ahora esto, eso no puedo debuggear nada.
Por si sirve de algo,  tengo el JDK: jdk16-146
Y el Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0)
Build id: 20211202-1639
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java vendor: Eclipse Adoptium
Java runtime version: 17.0.2+8
Java version: 17.0.2

Lo reinstalé y pasa lo mismo.
Lo de editar ahí en VM argumentes no me sirvio, tengo esto en Debug configurations:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien pudiera salvarme al vida, super agradecido. Ya que lo instalé hace pocos días, pero no es la primera vez que uso el Eclipse, y ya me viene poniendo varios palos en al rueda que no tienen nada que ver con errores de programacion, y elegí esto porque necesito hacer algo para leer archivos txt y con Java me parece bastante simple y accesible hacerlo, y que yo sepa los algoritmos los manejo bien, pero y si no logro solucionar esto ultimo probablemente abandone la programacion, porque aparentemente hay muy poca informacion sobre este problema, y si no logro Debuggear, pues ¿para qué voy a programar entonces?
Gracias por leer, y saludos

Comment: Sin más información es complicado saber nada: ¿usas el botón "debug" para lanzar la aplicación o la lanzas de manera independiente? ¿Qué configuración tienes para la ejecución? ¿es una aplicación de escritorio, usas un contenedor de aplicaciones como Tomcat?

Comment: Hola Pablo gracias por responder. Sí siempre lo usé y no tuve problema el boton debug. De repente dejó detenerse en breakpoints en cualquier proyecto.  Pero pude solucionarlo creo. Desinstalé el Eclipse Enterprise e instalé el Java for developers. Había instalado antes el Tomcat. Y es una aplicacion de escritorio siempre usando archivos .txt. Pero parece funcionar. Aparentemente tenia q encontrar la manera d desinstalarlo por completo sin q quede algo, salvo mis archivos d proyecto. Luego instalar el Java for Developers, pero no descarto que de repente me vuelva a suceder el problema. Saludos